# Shibboleth in sub-path URL

Tags: shibboleth

I am trying to install a Shibboleth Service Provider behind a reverse proxy, that handles SSL offloading and redirects all /shibboleth/ URLs to the VM that hosts Shibboleth SP with Apache. Here are some URL examples:

```
site.domain.com > go to website
site.domain.com/shibboleth/protectedURL1 > go to Shibboleth SP, first protected path
site.domain.com/shibboleth/protectedURL2 > go to Shibboleth SP, second protected path
```

In `shibboleth2.xml` I see that all handlers URLs are relative:

```
<Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="true"
   handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="false" ....
```

and examining SAML calls I see that Shibboleth URLs are missing the /shibboleth/ part:

https://site.domain.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

That link is indeed not working, but if I manually add /shibboleth/ : https://site.domain.com/shibboleth/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST it works.

Where I can configure shibboleth URLs, adding /shibboleth/?

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify `handlerURL` in `Sessions` section of shibboleth2.xml, then reconfigure Apache adding /shibboleth/ to all locations. I found a clue digging in Shibboleth documentation: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/Sessions#Sessions-AdvancedConfiguration

Here is my final `Sessions` section:

```
<Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false" handlerURL="/shibboleth/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="false" exportLocation="/GetAssertion" idpHistory="false" idpHistoryDays="7">
```